# Tool to save collection of pages in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I do a lot of work for various clients using SQL Server Management Studio (currently using version 18.5.1). Often, when working on a particular task, I'll have a bunch of pages open, with various views, stored procs, functions etc. If I close SSMS, it re-opens the tabs I've been working on, which is perfect.

However, if I then need to switch to work on something for another client, I have to work with a different set of Views, procs etc. So, I end up either closing all my tabs and starting again opening the views etc that I need for the other client's tasks, or opening a new instance of SSMS, which raises the (dread) possibility that I'll suddenly realise that I'm coding in the wrong instance, which is why none of my queries are working...

I'd like to find a tool that will save a collection of tabs and allow me to switch between them, so I'd have all the tabs for Client A in one group, then could close these and open all the tabs I was last using for Client B in a simple way.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you find a tool that archives what you want you will not have solved the main problem.

The main problem is that you can get distracted and run a query on the wrong customer.

My solution is this: use `SSMS` for **Client A** and `Azure Data Studio` for **Client B**.

This way you will easily notice on what customer you are on.